# Find the value located in the bottom row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I've got a table like this

[image]

What I want to do is get a formula that always gets the last value in column B and put it on cell D1, so in this case I want to get the value "21" but then if I keep adding values to this list I want to always get the value placed in the last row on that list. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is it a [Table or a Range](http://www.excelrush.com/excel-tables-vs-excel-data-range/)?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou It is a table of values that I update daily.

Comment: but is it a [Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c?ns=excel&version=19&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) which is a managed list in excel that can auto-expand, or just a range of values that you just call a table?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this.

=LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>""),B:B)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use `COUNTA(B:B)` to count all the non-empty cells in column B, use `ADDRESS()` to build the address of the last cell and use `INDIRECT()` to pull the value of the said address.

[image]

or you can use `INDEX()` to combine indirect and address

[image]